# The single word for "Volume per second"

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, time, measuring-units

Will anybody be able to mention the English word for "Volume per second (or preferably Volume per Time unit) or "Amount of task per a second"?

Thank you.

Comment: You're asking two distinct questions here. See answers below for variants on 'volume flow rate' (recognising that these are not everyday terms - 'flow rate' would probably be recognised by most men-in-the-street). 'Work rate' is an everyday term for how fast a person / machine is working, but isn't usually described in precise units. 'Power' in its scientific sense is defined in precise terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a general term describing some kind of processing I'd use "throughput"

As [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throughput_(business)) states:

> Throughput is the movement of inputs and outputs through a production process. [...] Throughput can be best described as the rate at which a system generates its products / services per unit of time.

Answer (score 2):

There is a French word "Débit" for the volume of fluid which passes through a given surface per unit time.

For English from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_rate):

> In physics and engineering, in particular fluid dynamics and
>   hydrometry, the **volumetric flow rate**, (also known as **volume flow rate**,
>   **rate of fluid flow** or **volume velocity**) is the volume of fluid which
>   passes through a given surface per unit time. The SI unit is m<sup>3</sup>·s<sup>−1</sup>
>   (cubic meters per second). In US Customary Units and British Imperial
>   Units, volumetric flow rate is often expressed as ft<sup>3</sup>/s (cubic feet
>   per second). It is usually represented by the symbol Q.

And the [French page](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9bit_%28physique%29)

Answer (score 0):

How about the term [*discharge*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discharge_%28hydrology%29) as used in hydrology?